# Get Selected columns from multidimensional array using DOT Notations keys array

Tags: php, arrays

I have following array

```
$users = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 16
            [name] => Dr. Arti Luthra
            [email] => artiluthra@dsingh.com
            [gender] => female
            [mobile] => 123456789
            [status] => 0
            [addresses] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 16
                            [clinic_name] => Luthra Medical Center
                            [address] => A-65/2, Meera Bhagh
                            [contact_no] => 2342345234
                            [formatted_address] => A-65/2, Meera Bhagh Rohini, West Delhi, Delhi
                            [timings] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [start] => 09:00 AM
                                            [end] => 02:00 PM
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [start] => 05:00 PM
                                            [end] => 08:00 PM
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 17
                            [clinic_name] => Luthra Medical Center
                            [address] => A-65/2, Chanakyapuri
                            [contact_no] => 123456789
                            [formatted_address] => A-65/2, Chanakyapuri Chanakyapuri, South Delhi, Delhi
                            [timings] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [start] => 09:00 AM
                                            [end] => 02:00 PM
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 39
            [name] => Sudhir Seth
            [email] => sudhirseth@gmail.com
            [gender] => male
            [mobile] => 65565656565
            [status] => 0
            [addresses] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 54
                            [clinic_name] => Dr. Sudhir Seth's Orthopoint
                            [address] => D-595, Chittranjan Park, Landmark: Besides Deshbandhu College, Delhi
                            [contact_no] => 
                            [formatted_address] => D-595, Chittranjan Park, Landmark: Besides Deshbandhu College, Delhi Greater Kailash, South Delhi, Delhi
                            [timings] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [start] => 10:30 AM
                                            [end] => 01:00 PM
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [start] => 06:00 PM
                                            [end] => 09:00 PM
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 55
                            [clinic_name] => Fortis C-Doc
                            [address] => B-16, Chirag Enclave, Nehru Place. Landmark: Opp. to Nehru Place, Delhi
                            [contact_no] => 
                            [formatted_address] => B-16, Chirag Enclave, Nehru Place. Landmark: Opp. to Nehru Place, Delhi Lajpat Nagar, South Delhi, Delhi
                            [timings] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [start] => 09:00 AM
                                            [end] => 11:00 AM
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I want to get selected keys using dot notation like

getKeys($users,array('name','email','addresses.address','addresses.clinic_name','addresses.timings.start'))

Using above getKeys() method the output should be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Dr. Arti Luthra
            [email] => artiluthra@dsingh.com
            [addresses] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [clinic_name] => Luthra Medical Center
                            [address] => A-65/2, Meera Bhagh
                            [timings] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [start] => 09:00 AM
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [start] => 05:00 PM
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [clinic_name] => Luthra Medical Center
                            [address] => A-65/2, Chanakyapuri
                            [timings] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [start] => 09:00 AM
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Sudhir Seth
            [email] => sudhirseth@gmail.com
            [addresses] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [clinic_name] => Dr. Sudhir Seth's Orthopoint
                            [address] => D-595, Chittranjan Park, Landmark: Besides Deshbandhu College, Delhi
                            [timings] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [start] => 10:30 AM
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [start] => 06:00 PM
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [clinic_name] => Fortis C-Doc
                            [address] => B-16, Chirag Enclave, Nehru Place. Landmark: Opp. to Nehru Place, Delhi
                            [timings] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [start] => 09:00 AM
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: yes, but unsuccessful :(

Comment: Hi @Rizier123 have you tried something ?

Comment: I really need that, too!

Comment: @JIM A bounty isn't the same as a big poster "I want free code!" — So, what have you tried/where did you fail?

Comment: maybe interesting? Already written routines for accessing arrays using dots... [treffynnon/Config.php](https://gist.github.com/treffynnon/563670/6d3d934eb5ca9916e1fef8f8cc08f89ea90a025e), also: [dflydev/dflydev-dot-access-data](https://github.com/dflydev/dflydev-dot-access-data),  also: [thesmart/php-dotty](https://libraries.io/github/thesmart/php-dotty),   also: [pklink/dotor](https://github.com/pklink/dotor)

Answer (score 3):

Seems that question very approximate to xPath for xml structures.

Also what interesting that there is jsonPath for json for example:

JsonPath in PHP - https://github.com/Skyscanner/JsonPath-PHP

JsonPath in Myqsl - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-path-syntax.html

But, unfortunately, for php array this technology have not implemented yet.

It is good point for writing your own library (phpPath)!

Regarding specifically your a little different case:

```
/**
 * Search values by phpPath
 *
 * @param array $aData
 * @param string|array $phpPath
 * @param array &$aReturn
 * @return array
 */
function getKeys($aData, $phpPath = [], &$aReturn = []) {

    //Support arrays of $phpPath
    if (is_array($phpPath)) {
        foreach ($phpPath as $path) {
            getKeys($aData, $path, $aReturn);
        }
        return $aReturn;
    }

    //Get next sought-for key
    $aParts = explode('.', $phpPath);
    $sNeedle = array_shift($aParts);
    $sRemain = implode('.', $aParts);

    foreach ($aData as $k => $v) {
        //skip numeric keys
        //@todo need to thinking about
        //needs to add * (wildcard) into phpPath for that purpose
        if (is_numeric($k) && $phpPath) {
            getKeys($v, $phpPath, $aReturn[$k]);
            continue;
        }

        //Is it key that we want
        if ($k !== $sNeedle) {
            continue;
        }

        //Checking needs deeper search
        if (is_array($v) && $sRemain) {
            getKeys($v, $sRemain, $aReturn[$k]);
            continue;
        }

        //Need to save fully-qualified found value
        $aReturn[$k] = $v;
        break;
    }

    return $aReturn;
}
```

Example of using:

```
var_dump(
    getKeys($users, array(
        'name', 'email', 'addresses.address', 
        'addresses.clinic_name', 'addresses.timings.start'
    ))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution will work.  It calls for a class that will create a string and then json_decode the string to create the array that you're seeking.  Two files were created, one that contains the class and another that instantiates an object from that class.

ArrayManager.php defines the class

```
class ArrayManager{

  var $out = '';

  function __construct($in, $params){
    $this->params = $params;
    $this->getKeys($in, $params);
    $this->out = json_decode($this->out, TRUE);
  }

  function getKeys($in, $params){
    $this->out = '[';
    $this->traverseArray($in);
    $this->out .= ']';
  }

  function traverseArray($in, $keyString='', $lastKey=''){
    if(!is_array($in)){
      if(in_array(substr($keyString, 1), $this->params)){
        $this->out .= '"'.$in.'",';
      }else{
        $this->out = rtrim($this->out, '"'.$lastKey.'":');
      }
      return;
    }

    $this->out .= '{';
    foreach($in as $key=>$value){
      $this->out .= '"'.$key.'":';
      if(is_numeric($key)){
        $result = $this->traverseArray($value, $keyString, $key);
        $this->out .= ',';
      }else{
        $result = $this->traverseArray($value, $keyString.'.'.$key, $key);
      }
    }
    $this->out = rtrim($this->out, ',');
    $this->out .= '}';
  }
}
```

runArrayManager.php just contains your sample array and code to call the ArrayManager class.

```
require_once('ArrayManager.php');

$params = array('name','email','addresses.address','addresses.clinic_name','addresses.timings.start');
$users =  *your sample array* 
$obj = new ArrayManager($users, $params);
$newArray = $obj->out;
```

Answer (score 0):

This function should handle a single path, delimited by a dot:

```
function map_path($path,$arr)
{
  if (($path=='')||(isEmpty($arr)))
    return array();
  $start=strpos($path,'.');
  if ($start>=0)
  {
   $prefix=substr($path,0,$start);
   $suffix=substr($path,$start+1);
   return array_map(function ($a) {return array(
       $prefix => map_path($suffix,$a))
    );},$arr);
  }
  else
    return array($path => $array[$path]);
}
```

In order to support multiple paths, simply iterate it:

```
$paths=array('name','email','addresses.address','addresses.clinic_name','addresses.timings.start');

$res=array();
for ($paths as $path)
   $res[$path]=map_path($path,$arr);
```